# Deploying an Angular 2 app built with webpack using Bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular, webpack, bitbucket

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question but have been unable to find one.

I am building an Angular 2 app that I would like hosted on an S3 bucket. There will be an EC2 (possibly) backend but that's another story. Ideally, I would like to be able to check my code into Bitbucket, and by some magic that alludes me I would like S3, or EC2, or whatever to notice via a hook, for instance, that the source has changed. Of course the source would have to be built using webpack and the distributables deployed correctly.

Now this seems like a pretty straightforward request but I can find no solution exception something pertaining to WebDeploy which I shall investigate right now.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Good news, AWS Lambda created for you.

You need to create following scenario and code to achieve your requirement.

1-Create Lambda function, this function should do the following steps:

- 1-1- Clone your latest code from GitHub or Bitbucket.

  ```
   1-2- install grunt or another builder for your angular app.

   1-3- install node modules.

   1-4- build your angular app.

   1-5- copy new build to your S3 bucket.

   1-6- Finish.
  ```

2-Create AWS API gateway with one resource and one method point to your Lambda function.

3-Goto your GitHub or Bitbucket settings and add webhook with your API gateway.

4-Enjoy life with AWS.
;)

Benefits:
1-You only charge when you have the new build.

2-Not need any machine or server (EC2).

3-You only maintain one function on Lambda.

for more info:

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

S3 isn't going to listen for Git hooks and fetch, build and deploy your code. BitBucket isn't going to build and deploy your code to S3. What you need is a service that sits in-between BitBucket and S3 that is triggered by a Git hook, fetches from Git, builds, and then deploys your code to S3. You need to search for Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment services which are designed to do this sort of thing.

AWS has [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/). You could setup your own [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) server. Or you could look into a service like [CodeShip](https://codeship.com/). Those are just a few of the many services out there that could accomplish this task. I think any of these services will require a bit of scripting on your part in order to get them to perform the actual webpack and copy to S3.